# How to change the default wordpress URL (or route) for search queries

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to alter the default wordpress search url for SEO tracking purposes. Right now when you search for a term the url displays like this - https://example.com/?s=green

I'm trying to get the search url to be formatted like this - https://example.com/search/?s=green

Is this even possible?

I tried the code below but it just converted the search terms into permalinks like this - https://example.com/search/green .... but what I need is https://example.com/search/?s=green

```
function redirect_search()
{
    if (is_search() && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
        wp_redirect(home_url("/search/". get_query_var('s')) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_search');
```

Many thanks for any help, it's great appreciated.